# Verify device ID with an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Athom Homey I can create my own scripts to preform different tasks.
For example check every device in the class light and if they matches an array they should turn on.
My first try Is just to display the devices that exists in both arrays.
If I skip my array and just use one of the ID's from the array myLights It prints only the name of that device.
How can I do that with the whole array?

```
//Fetch all devices from Homey
let devices = await Homey.devices.getDevices();

let myLights = [
//Fireplace_lightstrip
"fe5d4348-8842-438d-be7e-d03d772ddddd",
//Lightswitch_Hall 
"bc77b020-0388-42b5-9088-b329dbceeeee", 
//Chromecast_power
"b50c3c39-285d-4dba-8e4c-327621ffffff", //is not on the class light and should not be displayed
//Next
"four" //is not on the class light and should not be displayed
];

Object.values(devices).forEach(device => {
    if(device.class != 'light') return false;
      //if (device.id !== "bc77b020-0388-42b5-9088-b329dbcef7ba") return false;
      if (device.id !== myLights) return false;
        console.log(device.name);
          return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking against the entire array, we need one more loop:

```
    Object.values(devices).forEach(device => {
    if(device.class != 'light') return false;
      //if (device.id !== "bc77b020-0388-42b5-9088-b329dbcef7ba") return false;
      var result = myLights.filter((light) => device.id == light);
      if (result.length <= 0) return false;
        console.log(device.name);
          return true;
});
```

Comment: Aah, great thanks, will try this tonight. But isn't unnecessarily to filter the class twice? Can't I remove this line? if(device.class != 'light') return false;

Comment: @Makke_ No, that check has to be there. the variable light that i have added is each independent entry in the myLights array. Perhaps, I should have named it better.

Comment: Tried the code now. It writes all lights in log (console.log(device.name);) shouldn´t it only write those from my array which are lights?

Comment: @Makke_ aah..I have corrected the code in the reply. Please let me know if it works now.

Comment: :Works perfect! Thanks!